# Pandas multi-index unstack to single row

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, multi-index

I am pretty good with simple Pandas but am struggling with data reshaping and multi indices. I have a multindex dataframe that looks like so (it doesnt have to be a multindex but it seems the right thing to do)

| name | index | f1 | f2 | f3 | calc1 | calc2 | calc3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fox | 1 | red | white | fur | 0.21 | 1.67 | -0.34 |
|  | 2 |  |  |  | 0.76 | 2.20 | -1.02 |
|  | 3 |  |  |  | 0.01 | 1.12 | -0.22 |
| chicken | 1 | white | yellow | feathers | 0.04 | 1.18 | -2.01 |
|  | 2 |  |  |  | 0.18 | 0.73 | -1.21 |
| grain | 1 | yellow | bag | corn | 0.89 | 1.65 | -1.03 |
|  | 2 |  |  |  | 0.34 | 2.45 | -0.45 |
|  | 3 |  |  |  | 0.87 | 1.11 | -0.97 |

and all I want is:

| name | f1 | f2 | f3 | calc1_1 | calc2_1 | calc3_1 | calc1_2 | calc2_2 | calc3_2 | calc1_3 | calc2_3 | calc3_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fox | red | white | fur | 0.21 | 1.67 | -0.34 | 0.76 | 2.20 | -1.02 | 0.01 | 1.12 | -0.22 |
| chicken | white | yellow | feathers | 0.04 | 1.18 | -2.01 | 0.18 | 0.73 | -1.21 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| grain | yellow | bag | corn | 0.89 | 1.65 | -1.03 | 0.34 | 2.45 | -0.45 | 0.87 | 1.11 | -0.97 |

I figure this has got to be an easy one for the pandas gurus out there. Thanks all for your help!!

Drew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas-dataframe-unstack) to reshape to long format

```
new_df = df.set_index(['name', 'index', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3']).unstack('index')
```

OR via [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot)

```
new_df = df.pivot(index=['name', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'], columns='index')
```

---

Sort MultiIndex with [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index):

```
new_df = new_df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

---

Then reduce MultiIndex via [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html#pandas-index-map) + [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index):

```
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map(lambda s: '_'.join(map(str, s)))

new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
      name      f1      f2        f3  calc1_1  calc2_1  calc3_1  calc1_2  calc2_2  calc3_2  calc1_3  calc2_3  calc3_3
0  chicken   white  yellow  feathers     0.04     1.18    -2.01     0.18     0.73    -1.21      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      fox     red   white       fur     0.21     1.67    -0.34     0.76     2.20    -1.02     0.01     1.12    -0.22
2    grain  yellow     bag      corn     0.89     1.65    -1.03     0.34     2.45    -0.45     0.87     1.11    -0.97
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['fox', 'fox', 'fox', 'chicken', 'chicken', 'grain', 'grain',
             'grain'],
    'index': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'f1': ['red', 'red', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow'],
    'f2': ['white', 'white', 'white', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'bag', 'bag', 'bag'],
    'f3': ['fur', 'fur', 'fur', 'feathers', 'feathers', 'corn', 'corn', 'corn'],
    'calc1': [0.21, 0.76, 0.01, 0.04, 0.18, 0.89, 0.34, 0.87],
    'calc2': [1.67, 2.2, 1.12, 1.18, 0.73, 1.65, 2.45, 1.11],
    'calc3': [-0.34, -1.02, -0.22, -2.01, -1.21, -1.03, -0.45, -0.97]
})

new_df = (
    df.set_index(['name', 'index', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'])
        .unstack('index')
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
)

new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map(lambda s: '_'.join(map(str, s)))

new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```